# Magento 1.9.1.0 No Thumbnail Image in Category Menu

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

Is there any way to add thumbnail image in navigation menu? Magento 1.9.1.0 remove this feature in Magento Admin Panel. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Thanks,

Comment: just install with sample data and then truncate the products, categories, orders and attributes tables. By this data removed and thumbnail field remain visible.This is one method,If you get another one please let us know.I also have same error

Comment: Hi Shijin, what do you mean just install with a sample data? Do I need to populate my site with products? Then the thumbnail image in category will display? Let me know. Thanks,

Comment: I posted an answer that i will try,Please check.but carefull about attribute_id

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue via running the following queries in my phpMyAdmin,

1)

```
 INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, 
`attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, 
`frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, 
`is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES(140, 3, 'thumbnail', NULL, 
 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'image', 'Thumbnail
 Image', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

2)

```
 INSERT INTO `catalog_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `frontend_input_renderer`, 
`is_global`, `is_visible`, `is_searchable`, `is_filterable`, `is_comparable`, 
`is_visible_on_front`, `is_html_allowed_on_front`, `is_used_for_price_rules`, 
`is_filterable_in_search`, `used_in_product_listing`, `used_for_sort_by`, 
`is_configurable`, `apply_to`, `is_visible_in_advanced_search`, `position`, 
`is_wysiwyg_enabled`, `is_used_for_promo_rules`) VALUES 
 (140, NULL, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

3)

```
INSERT INTO `eav_entity_attribute` (`entity_attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`,  
`attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_id`, `attribute_id`, `sort_order`) 
VALUES (337, 3, 3, 4, 140, 3);
```

Here i am using attribute_id as 140,use an id for this in these queries by a unique value

to show this image in frontend,we can use

```
  <?php $thumbnail = $_category->getThumbnail(); ?> 
  <?php if($thumbnail): ?>

   <img src ="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS.$thumbnail; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>"  class="img-responsive"  />    

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Even after running your SQL, it appears that we can no longer call the category thumbnail with `getThumbnail()`?

Comment: All those queries do is create the attribute, add it to the database and then ensure it is all linked up. How are you actually displaying the category thumbnail in the frontend?

Comment: @zigojacko I updated the answer with frontend code,Please check it.I am only a beginner in magento, I don't know other methods.:)

Comment: What version of Magento are you running, are you sure it is 1.9.X? `getThumbnail()` doesn't load anything for me (the function didn't even exist in the category model, I had to manually create it)...

Comment: @zigojacko I am using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0,Which version you are using?

Comment: That's bizarre :/ When you installed Magento, did you install it with the sample data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72650/discussion-between-shijin-and-zigojacko).